# Black window covers almost the entire desktop / screen

Tags: graphics

A black window covers almost the entire desktop.
It looks like a broken terminal window.

I thought that the cause might be Intel proprietary drivers so I removed it, but that did not help.

Also, I noticed that the system boots without logo Ubuntu.

When I choose a particular kernel in GRUB (4.2.0-19), everything work fine, the problem does not occur.

When I start with the default kernel (4.2.0-35) I have this black window on my desktop.

I added a camera picture because when I made the screenshot, the black windows cannot be seen as if it were not there at all.

My computer is HP 530 Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2.

I will add that I am new to Linux.

[image: Black window covers almost the entire desktop]

```
*-display:0               
   description: VGA compatible controller  
   product: Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller  
   vendor: Intel Corporation  
   physical id: 2  
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0  
   version: 03  
   width: 32 bits  
   clock: 33MHz  
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom  
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0  
   resources: irq:16 memory:f0400000-f047ffff ioport:3000(size=8) memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0480000-f04bffff  
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED  
   description: Display controller  
   product: Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller  
   vendor: Intel Corporation  
   physical id: 2.1  
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1  
   version: 03  
   width: 32 bits  
   clock: 33MHz  
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list  
   configuration: latency=0  
   resources: memory:f0500000-f057ffff
```

When I switch tty, the black window fills the screen and is damaged, the font is unreadable.

[image: scrambled lines of text on black screen]

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problem. 
Launched `Xdiagnose` located in `/usr/share/applications` and selected *Disable bootloader graphics*.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen